# PHP OOP Multidimensional Array Search Issue

Tags: php

I have a function

```
function GetArrKey( $findArr, $key_arr, $depth=0 )
{
  if( count($key_arr) <= $depth || !array_key_exists($key_arr[$depth], $findArr) )
    return NULL;
  else if( count($key_arr) == $depth+1 )
    return $findArr[$key_arr[$depth]];

  return self::GetArrKey( $findArr[$key_arr[$depth]], $key_arr, $depth+1 );
}
```

That searches an array and returns the part of the array that matches what I need.

The only problem is it seems to be returning the exact same value. For example, I have this function in a foreach loop

```
foreach($e as $k => $v) {
  $value = GetArrayKey(array,$k);
  print_r($value);
}
```

and it's printing the exact same value 5 times (but the $k that I am using to search for is different each time).

I'm assuming it is because of the return self::GetArrKey but I can't seem to fix it.

Examples...

```
tweet-19486731414564564
Tweet 1
tweet-19486778435455556
Tweet 1
tweet-19703966855465458
Tweet 1
tweet-19842914654654650
Tweet 1
```

But it should do

```
tweet-19486731414564564
Tweet 1
tweet-19486778435455556
Tweet 2
tweet-19703966855465458
Tweet 3
tweet-19842914654654650
Tweet 4
```

Comment: Do you have some sample input?

Comment: What do you need? I added some example output.

Comment: I'm not following your example. Is that sample output, or sample input? What does `array` look like that you put into GetArrayKey? What does `$e` look like? This will be useful for being able to replicate your problem.

Comment: By the by, why the OOP tag in the title? I'm pretty sure this is really functional programming. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the last line of your recursive function:

```
return self::GetArrKey( $findArr[$key_arr[$depth]], $key_arr, $depth+1 );
```

This means that the function will be called again, until you hit a base case. The base case will return, and this function does not modify that case. Therefore all calls to the recursive function will return only the result of the base case, which is not what you want in this case because you're looking for a response rather than performing some function recursively.